# How can I install the driver for my AMD Radeon Graphics Card without disabling secure boot?

Tags: 17.10, amd-graphics, gpu-driver, amdgpu

I have a Dell Latitude E6440 with a Radeon Graphics Card and do not want to disable Secure Boot.

How can I install the proper drivers for the Card without disabling Secure Boot?

I found some posts mentioning loading self created certificates into the kernel but no real instructions on how to do it.

```
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520] [1002:6660] (rev ff)
```

Comment: If your BIOS or your graphics card does not support it that is never going to happen. Please provide details on both. Sometimes you can get it to work with a BIOS update.

Comment: @Rinzwind I added the `lscpi` output, BIOS should be Up-to-date and using UEFI Boot.